# How to connect a mySQL databse to spring boot in apache netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

sorry im really new to programming and for a school project i have to connect a website with a database, i have made the front-end but i dont know what to now. I have a controller here is its code, i dont know how to take input from my login page(`index.html`) any help would be helpful, even guiding me to certain resources would help. please let me know if any more information is needed. thank you.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MavenSbApplication 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MavenSbApplication.class, args);
    }
        
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String doSomething(Model model)
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

i tried watching a video but its different from what a friend did and im confused

Comment: You need to use [thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) in html to be able to pass data from html to spring boot

Answer (score 0):

It is not specific to NetBean.
From reading the code, I can see that you're using Spring Boot.

I don't know how you created your project. But I can confidently guess you used Maven. Add the following dependency to pom.xml if it is not there yet

```
    <dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>  
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>  
    </dependency>
```

Then in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=secret
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Assume you have a table `users` with id and name.

Create an User entity:
User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  private String name;
}
```

and a repository for it:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Then you can use it in a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/demo")
public class MainController {

@GetMapping(path="/all")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {

    return userRepository.findAll();
}
...
```

When you visit http://localhost:port/demo/all you can see all entries in table users

---

> i dont know how to take input from my login page(index.html)

For this sub-question, you can get value from the submitted form by adding a handler to controller that consume `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/login", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public void login(@RequestParam(value = "username") String userName,
                      @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {
// do some processing here
```